# delegate from one view to another

Tags: python, pyramid

I am using Pyramid with different views. I am wondering if it is possible to "delegate" parts of a views job to another view (another route).

For example:

```
http://localhost:6543/sample_project/testruns/testrun001/report.html?action=edit
=> delegate to:
http://localhost:6543/sample_project/testruns/testrun001/report.json
```

the views I am using:

```
# report:
@view_config(context=Root, route_name='report_route')
def report_view(context, request):
    ...
    if 'edit' in request.GET.getall('action'):
        # TODO: delegate to code_view
        ???
    ...
    # render report from report.json

# editor:
@view_config(context=Root, route_name='report_edit_route')
@view_config(context=Root, route_name='code_route')
def code_view(context, request):
    ....
```

Comment: I don't know Pyramid, but doesn't just `return code_view(context, request)` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly call views, they simply won't be going through the pyramid router mechanism which applies the `permission` and other such parameters to the view. Presumably if you are trying to call it, however, you already know these things.

In reality, you probably just want to refactor the common functionality into a separate function that each of your views can then delegate part of the work to.

Comment: thanks Michael! I will follow the refactoring approach. It sounds like a good advice to me.